# Why does switching OFF heavy electric loads cause a surge in voltage?

Tags: voltage, inductance, surge-protection

A voltage surge is a higher-than-normal voltage that temporarily exists on one or more power lines. Voltage surges are normally caused by the switching OFF of heavy electric loads.

I know that most of the heavy loads are inductive and inductive load produce a back EMF to oppose the sudden loss of voltage, but it won't go OVER voltage, it just induces an equal to the source voltage.

Why does switching OFF heavy electric loads cause a surge in voltage?

Comment: You're neglecting inductance in the power supply lines themselves.

Comment: Inductors produce a voltage to resist a change in current, not a change in voltage, so with a large enough change in current you can have an arbitrarily large change in voltage.  "back emf to oppose the sudden loss of voltage" sounds like you're mixing together the properties of an inductor and a capacitor into one device.

Comment: Question is unclear whether you are talking about inductive kick or flyback voltage, which is simply Lenz Law (and can be MUCH greater than the supply voltage), or the effect on the grid of suddenly removing a large load (temporary frequency and voltage increase).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know most of the heavy loads are inductive and inductive load produce a back emf to oppose the sudden loss of voltage, but it wont go OVER voltage, it just induce an equal to the source voltage.

You are not looking a large enough picture. The situation you describe here is when a source (an AC source) is gradually increasing or decreasing the current across an inductor.

But the full general picture is that the inductor produces an EMF that is proportional to the rate of change current. So if the supply is trying to increase the current the inductor can never produce a back EMF larger than the supply because the supply is the one driving the inductor (adding energy).

Similar to Newton and how the reaction force an object applies against as you push it can never be larger than the force you are applying to the object in order to accelerate it.

But things are different when the current is decreasing. Now, the inductor, not the supply, is the one driving the circuit. The decreasing current means that the inductor's magnetic field cannot be maintained at the same level and therefore collapses. That energy has to go somewhere. Another way to look at it is that the inductor wants to try and keep the current the same and uses the energy from its magnetic field to do so, which causes the magnetic field to collapse. It takes energy out of its magnetic field to produce a forward EMF to try and keep driving the current at the same level. This means that forward EMF is whatever voltage is necessary to cause this to happen which could be higher than the supply voltage if there is a high-impedance circuit element (i.e. an open switch) in the way.

Similar to Newton and how decelerating something causes the object to exert an force as the object tries to keep traveling at the same speed. If the deceleration is very fast (like hitting a wall) then this force can can be far higher than the force used to initially accelerate the object.

Trying to decelerate very quickly (like hitting a wall) is like flipping open a switch to interrupt the current (a very sudden change to high impedance) and produces very large forces and forward EMF. Decelerating slowly is like gradually increasing the impedance and will produce a smaller forward EMF much like how gradually braking a train causes the train to exert less force on the brakes and produces smaller forward EMF.